# How to pop up a message in Excel depending on the value of a cell range?

Tags: vba, excel

I have variable values in the cells of column A starting with cell A1. I want to write a VB code to popup different message boxes if the value in the targeted cells become equal to 12, and equal to 13, and so. But less than 12 no need a massage box to popup. The cells in the column A has formula which is relevant to the cells in same sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A24:A300")) = 13 Then 
        MsgBox "add 1 into the existing Forfeited PH value?" 
    End If 
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A24:A300")) = 14 Then 
        MsgBox "add 2 into the existing Forfeited PH value?" 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  SO is a place to have the community help find and correct issues with existing code.  If you have code you have tried please post it.  If what is wanted is for the community to write code from scratch, that is not what SO is for.

Comment: Thank You so much... this is the code I've been trying.

Comment: Post that code to your original post, and wrap with the code tags. (highlight the text, and click the {} button).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I think I understand your question to be stating that if the cell is changed to anything greater than 12 you need the message box to fire. This would be the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A300")) > 12 Then 
        MsgBox "add " & Target.value - 12 & " into the existing Forfeited PH value?" 
    End If 
End Sub
```

That is based on the existing message you have in your message box... I'm assuming based on the message that increasing the ph lowers the number so maybe the number is the acidity? Regardless. That should get the result you are looking for. In fact, if you don't want to limit it to 300 rows, you can just put your range as "A:A" and you can select the whole column as your field.
Ok after review of your spreadsheet the issue is you are not actually changing the target so all the target code is not useful ... please use the code below which should apply relative to the sheet you sent me in email. and be sure you of course save the file as an .xlsm file.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo eSub
 If (Worksheets("2015").Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5)) - 12 - Worksheets("2015").Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6))) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "add " & Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5)) - 12 & " into the Forfeited PH value?"
 End If
eSub:
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks immensely...but when I paste the code you suggested in cell A1 and ch ange the value in the linked cells it gives me the following massage: Run-time error '91'. 'Object Variable or with Block Variable not set'

Comment: Sorry ... Hmm I put that in my excel and it works... I'm not sure about "pasting into cell A1".  You put the code exactly as is into your VBA window into the Sheet you are making the changes on right? Because the action is "Worksheet_Change" it has to be put into the VBA window for the specific worksheet you are working with.

Comment: Did I do a wrong thing?... I click the cell A1 and click the view code in the developer and paste there. Any help to get rectified this problem would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: From there does it say Worksheet and Change in the top of the editor window? I added an image of what it should look like in my original answer.

Comment: Ok after some playing around I think I recreated your error. Two things.    1. You have to paste the code and save it before testing it or it will throw and error.  and    2. you have to save it as an .xlsm (Macro enabled workbook) in order to save a workbook with VBA in it or it will throw that error.

Comment: Sorry, I had to go off line for an urgent matter.... Yes, same as you mentioned... when I pasted in "view code"of developer I got 'Worksheet' and 'Change' in the top of the editor window.   Also, I saved it in Macro enable work book and reopened. But same error popups. Please note the cells in 'A' column linked with other cells in columns 'B' 'C' and 'D' and when the value of those cells changes the error comes even though the value of the cells of column 'A' less than 12. When I manually change the value of cells in column 'A' your code works perfectly, but formula will be erased.

Comment: do you have a way to put a link to your file somewhere I can get to it with example data so I can see more what you are trying to accomplish... I think my issue is that I'm confused about how the number changes that is being evaluated.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you please give me an email address so I can mail a part of the file in which you can add the code?

Comment: Christopher.gambill@yahoo.com

Comment: Thank you... I have emailed the file.

Comment: A gentle reminder about my request... kindly attend to it.

Comment: Sorry I was on the road all day yesterday. I'll take a look today and get back to you

Comment: sorry about the delay I added the adjusted code which seems to work in your workbook you sent me.

Comment: Thank you very much. When you get a free time would you kindly send me the file with your code? I really appreciate this.